# How to get the sequence flow info of between two activity from the Bpmn Instance java object of camunda?

Tags: activiti, camunda

I am developing the `go back` function.

This `go back` function only work to user task activity for now.

For make this clearly I simulate a process definition.

`StartEvent → → →squenceFlow_A→ → →A_UserTask→ → →squenceFlow_B → → →B_UserTask → → → endEvent.`

Assume the current activity at `B_UserTask`
This function need to do two step:

1.Start an execution at `squenceFlow_A`

2.Cancel the B_UserTask activity instance after the above step done.

But the question is how to get the info of `squenceFlow_A` from the BpmnInstance in java ?

I mean how to get the squenceflow info of between two activity from BpmnInstance in java ?

Maybe it is will be clearly if change the question to "How to get the first sequence Flow info that is before the given activity from BpmnInstance in java ?"

In aboce case this question is "how to get the first sequence Flow info that is before the  `B_UserTask` from BpmnInstance in java ?"

My english is so bad. Hope i will not make you guys feel bad from me.

By the way thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I finded the solution by myself.

Here is the code.

```
String givenActivityId = "activityId";
        BpmnModelInstance instance = repositoryService.getBpmnModelInstance("definitionId");
        Collection<SequenceFlow> sequenceFlows = instance.getModelElementsByType(SequenceFlow.class);
        for (SequenceFlow flow : sequenceFlows) {
            if (flow.getTarget().getId().equals(givenActivityId)) {
                LOG.info("Founded the sequenceFlow.");
                return flow;
            }
        }

        LOG.error("No such sequenceFlow");
```

cheers!!!

Comment: you can use node.getIncoming() or node.getOutgoing()